# Downstream performance while under network load

Tags: linux, networking, debian

I am trying to improve performance of my servers while under load. I am on a 1Gbit line and don't have an issue sending or receiving at capacity while idle.

These servers fetch, process, and then return data to users. rx:tx is almost 1:1. I noticed issues with my downstream while serving traffic to users and have been able to reproduce the issue with iperf3/wget. I've seen the issues on the web servers, and also load balancers (haproxy) sitting in front of them.

If I run iperf3 -P 4 -R (4 parallel streams receiving data) or wget alone, it goes at 1Gbit. If I run them both at the same time total server usage drops under 500Mbit and bounces all over the place. Stopping one causes the other to go back up to 1Gbit.

Transmitting works just fine @ 1Gbit while under load, as well as downloading within the datacenter.

The machines are running dual Xeon L5630 with a mix of Broadcom and Intel NICs. I've tried a variety of tweaks to improve performance nothing seems to help.

I've been told that the issue is with processing interrupts quick enough. And in the process of researching this I have determined there's no one size fits all solution for performance optimization. I would love if I could figure this out myself, but would be happy to hire someone as well.

Does anyone have recommendations as to where to start?

Is it most likely interrupts? I loaded up irqbalance, then turned it off and assigned nic queues to different cores by hand.

Tried tweaking ring buffers and sysctl parameters and countless things. Not sure where to go from here.

Would appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Here's some output of the current sysctl tweaks, ethtool, system info:
fs.file-max = 4953281
kernel.panic = 10
kernel.pid_max = 4194303
net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 65535
net.core.somaxconn = 65535
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 1024 65535
net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control = htcp
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 15
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 65535
net.ipv4.tcp_max_tw_buckets = 1440000
net.ipv4.tcp_rfc1337 = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096    87380   33554432
net.ipv4.tcp_slow_start_after_idle = 0
net.ipv4.tcp_synack_retries = 3
net.ipv4.tcp_syn_retries = 3
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 0
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 0
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096    65536   16777216
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 0
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_established = 60
net.nf_conntrack_max = 800000
vm.overcommit_memory = 1

ethtool -i eth0
driver: igb
version: 5.0.5-k
firmware-version: 1.7.2
bus-info: 0000:02:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: yes
supports-eeprom-access: yes
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: no

## ethtool -S eth0|grep -v ": 0"

NIC statistics:
     rx_packets: 2489111423
     tx_packets: 2608653369
     rx_bytes: 2862551932229
     tx_bytes: 1845742794294
     rx_broadcast: 187617
     tx_broadcast: 1
     rx_missed_errors: 102
     tx_tcp_seg_good: 2977380
     rx_long_byte_count: 2862551932229
     rx_fifo_errors: 488
     tx_queue_0_packets: 324825232
     tx_queue_0_bytes: 231519953294
     tx_queue_0_restart: 1093
     tx_queue_1_packets: 327114999
     tx_queue_1_bytes: 229028327215
     tx_queue_1_restart: 1085
     tx_queue_2_packets: 329640953
     tx_queue_2_bytes: 232597728986
     tx_queue_2_restart: 538
     tx_queue_3_packets: 325861970
     tx_queue_3_bytes: 224621464319
     tx_queue_3_restart: 1132
     tx_queue_4_packets: 323541155
     tx_queue_4_bytes: 228741007431
     tx_queue_4_restart: 829
     tx_queue_5_packets: 330539393
     tx_queue_5_bytes: 235725634025
     tx_queue_5_restart: 601
     tx_queue_6_packets: 320796966
     tx_queue_6_bytes: 222150341311
     tx_queue_6_restart: 3705
     tx_queue_7_packets: 326332702
     tx_queue_7_bytes: 230422874757
     tx_queue_7_restart: 953
     rx_queue_0_packets: 317746938
     rx_queue_0_bytes: 358943545445
     rx_queue_0_csum_err: 80
     rx_queue_1_packets: 310501723
     rx_queue_1_bytes: 354800450890
     rx_queue_1_drops: 386
     rx_queue_1_csum_err: 92
     rx_queue_2_packets: 304246179
     rx_queue_2_bytes: 346027873804
     rx_queue_2_csum_err: 76
     rx_queue_3_packets: 307838541
     rx_queue_3_bytes: 353811008950
     rx_queue_3_csum_err: 149
     rx_queue_4_packets: 310871839
     rx_queue_4_bytes: 359145884376
     rx_queue_4_csum_err: 69
     rx_queue_5_packets: 317043674
     rx_queue_5_bytes: 364702136702
     rx_queue_5_csum_err: 96
     rx_queue_6_packets: 312282264
     rx_queue_6_bytes: 358149543411
     rx_queue_6_csum_err: 91
     rx_queue_7_packets: 308579883
     rx_queue_7_bytes: 357015009991
     rx_queue_7_csum_err: 115

Dual: model name    : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           L5630  @ 2.13GHz (16 cores total over 2 physical processors)
48GB ram

(irqbalance in charge)
/proc/interrupts:
  64:          2          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          2          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      eth0
  65:       5123      13851          0          0       6115          0  221059968          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      eth0-TxRx-0
  66:      11343          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  219834257       5371          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      eth0-TxRx-1
  67:      11054          0          0          0  217177269          0          0          0          0          0      15812          0          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      eth0-TxRx-2
  68:      18435          0          0          0          0          0          0  220400185          0          0          0          0       6581      17136          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      eth0-TxRx-3
  69:      11528          0          0          0       4829          0          0          0          0          0          0          0      11794  215368998          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      eth0-TxRx-4
  70:      11594          0          0          0          0  220027516          0          0          0          0          0          0       4306          0          0      17515   PCI-MSI-edge      eth0-TxRx-5
  71:      18647  214603111          0          0       4567          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0      11380          0   PCI-MSI-edge      eth0-TxRx-6
  72:      10266          0          0  216763545          0          0          0          0          0      13147          0          0       3458          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      eth0-TxRx-7

## cat /proc/net/softnet_stat

22d4ab38 00000000 0000002b 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 0952491e 00000000
23aabf38 00000000 00000017 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 0833ce65 00000000
22f9f396 00000000 00000010 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 09934c0d 00000000
2391f6b5 00000000 0000000d 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 0845c0a9 00000000
01418f3b 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
01768b3e 00000000 00000004 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
015a3626 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
014e9af3 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
0013582d 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
0014919d 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
0020ba05 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
0146569d 00000000 00000007 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
00165ba1 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
016872b1 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
0013dc0b 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
0014d61d 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000